# Casting GetWindowLongPtr() to a templated type failed

Tags: c++, templates, winapi

I started working on a free project to create my own rendering-engine in OpenGL
I already created one in DirectX and wanted to explore new things.
My DirectX engine had some flaws here and there so I wanted to correct them inside my OpenGl engine.

Currently I' trying to create a new window to render my geometry too. I want my window class to be reuable so I made a template class of it:

```
    #ifndef _IWINDOW_H
    #define _IWINDOW_H

    #ifndef _WINDOWS_
        #include <windows.h>
    #endif
    #ifndef _STRING_H
        #include "string.h"
    #endif

    template<class T>
    class IWindow
    {
    public:
        IWindow();
        virtual ~IWindow();

        static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

        virtual LRESULT handleEvent(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) = 0;

        virtual BYTE getWindowBitsPerPixel() const = 0;

        virtual long getWindowWidth() const = 0;
        virtual long getWindowHeight() const = 0;

        virtual const std::tstring getWindowTitle() const = 0;
        virtual const std::tstring getWindowClassName() const = 0;

        HWND getWindowHandle();
        HINSTANCE getWindowInstance();

    protected:
        bool createWindow();
        bool destroyWindow();

        void setExtendedStyle(DWORD extendedStyle);
        void setStyle(DWORD style);

        DWORD getExtentedStyle() const;
        DWORD getStyle() const;

        RECT getWindowRect() const;

    private:
        bool setupWindow();
        bool errorHandling();

        WNDCLASS createWindowClass();
        RECT createWindowRect();
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR createWindowPixelFormatDescription();

        HGLRC           handle_resourcecontext;
        HDC             handle_devicecontext;
        HWND            handle_window;
        HINSTANCE       handle_instance;

        RECT            window_rect;

        DWORD           extended_style;
        DWORD           style;

        unsigned int    pixel_format;
    };

    template<class T>
    IWindow<T>::IWindow()
        : handle_resourcecontext(0)
        , handle_devicecontext(0)
        , handle_window(0)
        , handle_instance(GetModuleHandle(NULL))

        , window_rect()

        , extended_style(0)
        , style(0)

        , pixel_format(0)
    {}
    template<class T>
    IWindow<T>::~IWindow()
    {}

    template<class T>
    LRESULT CALLBACK IWindow<T>::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_CREATE)
        {
            // if the message is WM_CREATE, the lParam contains a pointer to a CREATESTRUCT
            // the CREATESTRUCT contains the "this" pointer from the CreateWindow method
            // the "this" pointer of our app is stored in the createstruct pcs->lpCreateParams
            CREATESTRUCT *pCS = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pCS->lpCreateParams);
        }
        else
        {
            //retrieve the stored "this" pointer

            LONG value = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

            T* window = (T*)(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            if (window != nullptr)
                return window->handleEvent(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    template<class T>
    bool IWindow<T>::createWindow()
    {
        this->window_rect = createWindowRect();

        if (!RegisterClass(&createWindowClass()))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed To Register The Window Class."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (!setupWindow())
            return FALSE;
        if (!errorHandling())
            return FALSE;

        ShowWindow(this->handle_window, SW_SHOW);
        SetForegroundWindow(this->handle_window);
        SetFocus(this->handle_window);

        return TRUE;
    }
    template<class T>
    bool IWindow<T>::destroyWindow()
    {
        LPCTSTR window_classname = getWindowClassName().c_str();

        if (this->handle_resourcecontext)
        {
            if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)) MessageBox(NULL, _T("Release Of DC And RC Failed."), _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            if (!wglDeleteContext(this->handle_resourcecontext)) MessageBox(NULL, _T("Release Rendering Context Failed."), _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

            this->handle_resourcecontext = NULL;
        }

        if (this->handle_devicecontext && !ReleaseDC(this->handle_window, this->handle_devicecontext))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Release Device Context Failed."), _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            this->handle_devicecontext = NULL;
        }
        if (this->handle_window && !DestroyWindow(this->handle_window))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could Not Release hWnd."), _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            this->handle_window = NULL;
        }

        if (!UnregisterClass(_T("classname"), this->handle_instance))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could Not Unregister Class."), _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            this->handle_instance = NULL;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    template<class T>
    void IWindow<T>::setExtendedStyle(DWORD extendedStyle)
    {
        this->extended_style = extendedStyle;
    }
    template<class T>
    void IWindow<T>::setStyle(DWORD style)
    {
        this->style = style;
    }

    template<class T>
    DWORD IWindow<T>::getExtentedStyle() const
    {
        return this->extended_style;
    }
    template<class T>
    DWORD IWindow<T>::getStyle() const
    {
        return this->style;
    }

    template<class T>
    RECT IWindow<T>::getWindowRect() const
    {
        return this->window_rect;
    }

    template<class T>
    bool IWindow<T>::setupWindow()
    {
        LPCTSTR window_classname = getWindowClassName().c_str();
        LPCTSTR window_title = getWindowTitle().c_str();

        this->handle_window = CreateWindowEx(this->extended_style,
            _T("classname"),
            window_title,
            this->style |
            WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
            WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
            0, 0,
            this->window_rect.right - this->window_rect.left,
            this->window_rect.bottom - this->window_rect.top,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            this->handle_instance,
            this);

        int error = GetLastError();
        if (!this->handle_window)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Creation Error."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    template<class T>
    bool IWindow<T>::errorHandling()
    {
        //Check if we have a device context
        if (!(this->handle_devicecontext = GetDC(this->handle_window)))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Create A GL Device Context."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Check the pixel format
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = createWindowPixelFormatDescription();

        this->pixel_format = ChoosePixelFormat(this->handle_devicecontext, &pfd);
        if (!this->pixel_format)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!SetPixelFormat(this->handle_devicecontext, this->pixel_format, &pfd))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Set The PixelFormat."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Check if the open gl context is succesfully created
        this->handle_resourcecontext = wglCreateContext(this->handle_devicecontext);
        if (!this->handle_resourcecontext)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Create A GL Rendering Context."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!wglMakeCurrent(this->handle_devicecontext, this->handle_resourcecontext))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Activate The GL Rendering Context."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    template<class T>
    WNDCLASS IWindow<T>::createWindowClass()
    {
        LPCTSTR window_classname = getWindowClassName().c_str();

        WNDCLASS wc;

        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(LONG_PTR);
        wc.hInstance = this->handle_instance;

        //TODO: load the cursor and application icon!
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

        wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = _T("classname");

        return wc;
    }
    template<class T>
    RECT IWindow<T>::createWindowRect()
    {
        return RECT
        {
            (long)0,
            (long)0,
            (long)getWindowWidth(),
            (long)getWindowHeight()
        };
    }
    template<class T>
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR IWindow<T>::createWindowPixelFormatDescription()
    {
        return PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
            1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
            PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
            PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
            getWindowBitsPerPixel(),
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            16,
            0,
            0,
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
            0,
            0, 0, 0
        };
    }

    template<class T>
    HWND IWindow<T>::getWindowHandle()
    {
        return this->handle_window;
    }
    template<class T>
    HINSTANCE IWindow<T>::getWindowInstance()
    {
        return this->handle_instance;
    }

    #endif //_IWINDOW_H
```

If I than create an instance of this class it will look something like this:

```
#ifndef _WINDOW_H
#define _WINDOW_H

#include "System.h"
#include "IWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public System, public IWindow<MainWindow>
{
public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

    virtual bool initialize();
    virtual void update();
    virtual bool shutDown();

    bool setFullscreen(bool fullscreen);
    bool getFullscreen() const;

    virtual LRESULT handleEvent(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

    virtual BYTE getWindowBitsPerPixel() const;

    virtual long getWindowWidth() const;
    virtual long getWindowHeight() const;

    virtual const std::tstring getWindowTitle() const;
    virtual const std::tstring getWindowClassName() const;

private:

};

#endif //_WINDOW_H
```

With the corresponding source file:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>

#ifndef _STRING_H
    #include "string.h"
#endif

#include "WorldSettings.h"
#include "ApplicationSettings.h"

#include "SystemType.h"

#include "Singleton.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
    :System(SystemType::WINDOW_SYSTEM)
{
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

bool MainWindow::initialize()
{
    if (!createWindow())
    {
        shutDown();
        return FALSE;
    }

    return true;
}
void MainWindow::update()
{

}
bool MainWindow::shutDown()
{
    ApplicationSettings settings = Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings();

    if (settings.getFullscreen())
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);                 
        ShowCursor(TRUE);                               
    }

    destroyWindow();

    return TRUE;
}

bool MainWindow::setFullscreen(bool fullscreen)
{
    ApplicationSettings settings = Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings();

    if (settings.getFullscreen() == fullscreen)
        return true;

    if (fullscreen)
    {
        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));

        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = settings.getWindowWidth();
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = settings.getWindowHeight();
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = settings.getBitsPerPixel();
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
        {
            if (MessageBox(NULL, _T("The Requested Fullscreen Mode Is Not Supported By\nYour Video Card. Use Windowed Mode Instead?"), _T("NeHe GL"), MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) == IDYES)
            {
                settings.setFullscreen(FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Program Will Now Close."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    if (settings.getFullscreen())
    {
        setExtendedStyle(WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        setStyle(WS_POPUP);

        ShowCursor(FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        setExtendedStyle(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE);
        setStyle(WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

        ShowCursor(TRUE);
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&getWindowRect(), getStyle(), FALSE, getExtentedStyle());

    //If the settings have been changed apply them to the worldsettings
    Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().setApplicationSettings(settings);

    return TRUE;
}
bool MainWindow::getFullscreen() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getFullscreen();
}

LRESULT MainWindow::handleEvent(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
    {
        if (!HIWORD(wParam))
        {
            activate();
        }
        else
        {
            deactivate();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case SC_SCREENSAVE:
        case SC_MONITORPOWER:
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    //case WM_SIZE:                             
    //{
    //  ReSizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    //  return 0;                               
    //}
    }


    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

BYTE MainWindow::getWindowBitsPerPixel() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getBitsPerPixel();
}

long MainWindow::getWindowWidth() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getWindowWidth();
}
long MainWindow::getWindowHeight() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getWindowHeight();
}

const std::tstring MainWindow::getWindowTitle() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getWindowTitle();
}
const std::tstring MainWindow::getWindowClassName() const
{
    return Singleton<WorldSettings>::getInstance().getApplicationSettings().getWindowTitle();
}
```

The problem is that whenever I create my mainwindow using CreateWindowEx(...) the cast inside the WndProc function always fails. 
I've given the "this" pointer as last parameter to the CreateWindowEx(...) function to retrieve it from the GetWindowLongPtr(...) method inside the WndProc function. This way I can call a custom event handling method of the class itself to use a more "Object-Oriented" design.

If anybody could see what I'm doing wrong here, I would love to hear it.
Thanks in advance for reading this long post.

Kind regards.
Dyronix.

Comment: A C-style cast never "fails".  You'll need to describe "fails" better.

Comment: SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pCS->lpCreateParams); - already error, because LONG != LONG_PTR on x64. but in what problem look under debugger - which pointer you pass to CreateWindowEx, what in pCS->lpCreateParams (you can use this already on WM_NCCREATE), what is got GetWindowLongPtr. again in what problem use debugger and/or dbgprint ??

Comment: Unrelated, your choice of preprocessor macro names for fence posts are reserved, and in your case, particular likely to be conflicting (`_WINDOW_H`).  Per the C11 standard, "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." - in short, don't do that. Change them.

Comment: Btw: the fail was that I had an "Access Vialation Reading Location" because the C-style cast "casted" to a wrong type I suppose.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. For one thing, it isn't necessary to read through your entire DirectX/OpenGL history. It's unrelated to your issue. Next up, a class template that never uses its type parameter is useless. And there really is nothing *minimal* about your [mcve]. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38265020/edit) your question, and strip off all the unrelated clutter (epic intro, unrelated code).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
Instead of casting to the template class I could just cast the void pointer to the type of the base class since every class would inherit from it the right method will get called anyway

```
LRESULT CALLBACK IWindow<T>::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CREATE)
    {
        // if the message is WM_CREATE, the lParam contains a pointer to a CREATESTRUCT
        // the CREATESTRUCT contains the "this" pointer from the CreateWindow method
        // the "this" pointer of our app is stored in the createstruct pcs->lpCreateParams
        CREATESTRUCT *pCS = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pCS->lpCreateParams);
    }
    else
    {
        //retrieve the stored "this" pointer
        LONG value = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

        IWindow* window = (IWindow*)(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        if (window != nullptr)
            return window->handleEvent(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

So actually I'm not 100% sure of the but the template class is not needed and can just be removed. I first thought I need to create a different instance of every new class to be able to make the WndProc work, but I think that you only need one WndProc/Application and that it will catch all the window messages from all the active windows.

In any case, if this is the case you can remove the template class if it not I can just keep it. the solution worked for both methods.

Comment: Why is the class a template class anyway? You aren't actually using the template argument anywhere, at least not as far as I can see. Also you still need to fix your incorrect `LONG` casts in the call to `SetWindowLongPtr()`; they MUST be `LONG_PTR` instead.

Comment: I already did, I just copied the code from above and edited it so it does not break anymore.
I first thought I needed to create a different instance of every new class to be able to make the WndProc work, but I think that you only need one WndProc/Application and that it will catch all the window messages from all the active windows.

Comment: That isn't exactly true. Each window procedure is tied to a window class. All windows of the same class use the same procedure. It's not application-global, it's class-global. You can register another window class that uses a different window procedure.

Comment: Yes, the template is not needed. But if you do use a template, the cast should be to `IWindow<T>*` instead of `IWindow*`. Also, you are calling `GetWindowLongPtr()` twice and ignoring your `value` from the first call. And `WM_CREATE` is not the first message a window receives, `WM_NCCREATE` is the first message that provides access to the `lParam` from `CreateWindow/Ex()`, so you should call `SetWindowLongPtr()` in reply to `WM_NCCREATE` instead of `WM_CREATE`.